# How to remove window eventListener in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

This peace of code shows **user mouse coordinates**, it works properly.

But I also want to **remove event handler by clicking the STOP button**. Unfortunately, this seems to be wrong somehow because event handler still tracking and changing *position* even after clicking the button:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function MouseCords() {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 })

    function mouseMoveHandler(event) {
        setPosition({
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <pre>
                x: {position.x}
                <br />
                y: {position.y}
            </pre>
            <button
                onClick={() =>
                    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
                }
            >
                STOP
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I guess there might be a problem with *context*, but I am not sure what to do to solve it.

By the way, this is React component and I am using it in App.js like this:

```
import MouseCords from './components/MouseCords'

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MouseCords />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You need to store a reference to the `mouseMoveHandler` that you used in adding the listener, which may be different than the reference in your click callback since you're declaring the function at the top level of the component. Otherwise use `useCallback` to ensure that `mouseMoveHandler` isn't redeclared on each render. You'll also want to provide a cleanup in your useEffect so that the listener is removed on component unmount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function declared at the top level of a component will be redeclared on every render, as will the anonymous function in the button's `onClick` property. As such, when you try to remove the listener the function reference in the click handler won't match the function reference that the listener was set with and so it won't work.

The simplest solution is to declare the function using [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) which will ensure that the function is only declared on first render (due to the empty dependency array) and so the click handler and useEffect function references will match.

You should also always provide a ['cleanup' function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) by returning a function from your `useEffect` that will clean up on unmount any side-effects the useEffect my have caused during the lifecycle of the component.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

function MouseCoords() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const mouseMoveHandler = useCallback((event) => {
    setPosition({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        x: {position.x}
        <br />
        y: {position.y}
      </pre>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
        }
      >
        STOP
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<MouseCoords />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Alternatively you could handle the listener entirely through the `useEffect` and use a boolean flag to conditionally add/remove the listener everytime it changes. In this case the 'cleanup' will run each time there is a change in the dependency array.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

function MouseCoords() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [shouldTrack, setShouldTrack] = useState(true);

  const mouseMoveHandler = useCallback((event) => {
    setPosition({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldTrack) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
      };
    }
  }, [shouldTrack]);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        x: {position.x}
        <br />
        y: {position.y}
      </pre>
      <button
        onClick={() => setShouldTrack(b => !b)}
      >
        {shouldTrack ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<MouseCoords />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is such an elegant solution, works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)

return window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
    }, [])
```

Comment: This won't help the click handler removing the listener